# Как сделать генератор квадратиков

Tags: python-3.x, алгоритм, pygame

я разрабатываю 2D игру на Python 3.8, на Pygame .И я столкнулся с проблемой одной.
Мне нужен генератор квадратиков примерно 45 на 45.

Comment: А что такое "генератор квадратиков" ?

Comment: Скрипт который рисует и создаёт новый объект "Квадрат" 45 на 45

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
import pygame

def sq_gen():
    left, top = 0, 0
    while True:
        left, top = yield pygame.Rect(left, top, 45, 45)

sqs = sq_gen()
next(sqs)
for i in range(10):
    sq = sqs.send((i,i))
    print(sq)
```

Вывод:

```
<rect(0, 0, 45, 45)>
<rect(1, 1, 45, 45)>
<rect(2, 2, 45, 45)>
<rect(3, 3, 45, 45)>
<rect(4, 4, 45, 45)>
<rect(5, 5, 45, 45)>
<rect(6, 6, 45, 45)>
<rect(7, 7, 45, 45)>
<rect(8, 8, 45, 45)>
<rect(9, 9, 45, 45)>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!